# Android set default keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

i want to set scandinavian keyboard as default keyboard on an android device and
i want to do this by code.
So i try with InputMethodManager :

```
InputMethodManager mng = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(LoginActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
List<InputMethodInfo> m_list=mng.getInputMethodList();
```

and i find the method setInputMethod  (IBinder  token, String  id) of the InputMethodManager class. But i don't find examples/documentation that explain me how to use it.Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Hi everybody, i want to set scandinavian keyboard as default keyboard on an android device and i want to do this by code.

You cannot modify the "default keyboard on an android device" via code from a standard SDK application. The user can choose their own keyboard and locale via the Settings application. You can send users to the proper Settings screen via `ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS` and `ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS`, which are activity `Intent` actions defined on `android.provider.Settings`.

Applications that are part of the device firmware can use `DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD` on `android.provider.Settings.Secure`.