# Disable Swype keyboard for edit text

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I have only a `EditText` in my fragment. I  want user not to use `Swype Keyboard` for that particular `EditText`. How can I disable it and allow user to type using other keyboard available.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard used is ultimately up to the user to decide and can not be changed by a developer without really going against Androids guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you cannot change your default keyboard by code with standard SDK...

The solution you can implement is send the user to the settings so he can change it.

See [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916184/android-set-default-keyboard) that explains how to do it.