# How can I turn off top bar shortcuts from Xamarin keyboard?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, android-softkeyboard

I require a plain clean keyboard when I click on an entry, but I keep getting "gif" "google search" "emoji" features on the keyboard.

I've tried setting the keyboard prop to "Default" and "Text" but neither seems to help.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916184/android-set-default-keyboard

Comment: The "gif" "google search" etc are the default selections of Android device. It seems to be hardly to remove them. You can create a Entry custom renderer to customize a keyboard. You can refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787385/custom-keyboard-in-xamarin-forms